# What is the most elegant way to name and event handle site with 100's of input boxes?

Tags: ajax, input, jquery-selectors, event-handling, huge-pages

Basically so I’ve got this application style webpage with hundreds of input fields(Hidden across tab’s and accordians / fake dialog boxes etc…) , and I want as soon as the control has lost focus / the keystroke ‘enter / tab’ has been hit, (Rather than a submit) I want to using AJAX send a post back to the server to update that field.

Now when trying to figure out naming conventions / tags / classes etc I started going around a little bit in circles as to how to best name things to best utilise Jquery’s selector capabilities at the same time as being concise with event handling.

So my plan was to have a table in the backend db that has in it the table architecture of virtually the entire db, with a unique id and location descriptors (Table / fldName / data type etc…). I was thinking of using that unique id as the id assigned to each of the input elements in the html; and then setting up a single event listener on the whole wrapped set of input’s, that then

—        references an array which basically has that dbFields info in it by the id’s

—        check clientSide security

—        data validation

—        send the value with the id to the php

o        php then does server side security checks ? data validation again.

o        php sends to the relevant stored procedure to update the info

So my question is; is that an elegant way of referencing all the inputs in a way so I set up a generic listener that is called on any input update?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

the word/phrase you are seeking is "javascript MVC"

(likely) all are designed for event handling and ajax.

http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

i use backbone and its stunning. im sure you can abstract exactly the function you wish in many or all of these MVCs.